# read and write data (incomplete entries coming)

Tags: php, mysql

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT post,replier FROM book1");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
   $replier = $row['replier'];
   $some = $row['post'];

   $wors = strip_tags($some);

   $query = "INSERT INTO words VALUES('$wors','$replier')";
   $up= mysql_query($query);
   }
```

i have to take data from database strip html and put it in another databse 
however with the above code only half the data is getting stored in the 2nd database,although when i display all records are displayed from 1st db.

whats wrong here?

Comment: its only putting half the records from book1 to values..i am quite puzzled why!

Comment: 2 databases means 2 mysql resources/connections

Comment: @Sandwolf0x37 sorry for the wrong edit ,i meant table value and book1

Comment: Darhazer is probably correct, what what is "half" the data....half the number of rows you're expecting, or all the rows, but half the characters of the column?

Comment: half of the rows of initial data, and yes the solution worked ,thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have auto-SQL injection. If some of the HTML stored in first DB contain quotes, it will break the next query. So, escape the values!

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT post,replier FROM book1");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
   $replier = mysql_real_escape_string($row['replier']);
   $wors = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($row['post']));

   $query = "INSERT INTO words VALUES('$wors','$replier')";
   $up= mysql_query($query);
   }
```